# Randomly call a method

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have 7 methods in a class. When i receive a specific message i have to call a method randomly from those 7 methods.
My sample code is:

```
-(void)poemAbcd{

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"abcd_bg.png"];
    [backgroundImage setImage:image];

    [self changeMumuPosition:80 with:220];
}

-(void)poemHumptyDumpty{

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"humpty_dumpty.png"];
    [backgroundImage setImage:image];

    [self changeMumuPosition:80 with:170];
}

-(void)poemBlackship{

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"black_sheep.png"];
    [backgroundImage setImage:image];

    [self changeMumuPosition:66 with:229];
}

-(void)poemRowRow{

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"boat_bg.png"];
    [backgroundImage setImage:image];

    [self changeMumuPosition:144 with:211];
}

-(void)poemHappy{

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"boat_bg.png"];
    [backgroundImage setImage:image];

    [self changeMumuPosition:144 with:211];
}

-(void)poemItsyBitsy{

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"boat_bg.png"];
    [backgroundImage setImage:image];

    [self changeMumuPosition:144 with:211];
}

-(void)poemTwinkleTwinkle{

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"twincle_twincle_little_star.png"];
    [backgroundImage setImage:image];

    [self changeMumuPosition:70 with:222];
}
```

Into the following method I want to call a method randomly from those 7 methods.

```
-(void)poemRandom{

      //Call a method randomly from those 7 methods

}
```

How can i do so? Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: What do you mean by "Randomly" here ?

Comment: Rather than randomly call a method, since all of them do the same task (just some difference in data), you can encapsulate the data and randomly pick which set of data to display instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sloppy way to do it:

```
-(void)poemRandom{
  int nr = arc4random() % 7;
  if (nr == 0) [self poemAbcd];
  else if (nr == 1) [self poemHumptyDumpty];
  else if (nr == 2) [self poemBlackship];
  //and so on
}
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 6):

One way to do it is to add function pointers to an array and pick one from there. `SEL` is a way to wrap selectors in objective-c, so you can use something along the lines of

```
// edited, fixed data structure, props to xlc
// don't forget to set array size according to function count
SEL funcionsArray[7] = { @selector(poemAbcd), @selector(poemHumptyDumpty), /* etc */ };
// randomIndex is a randomly selected number from 0 to [number-of-selectors] - 1
SEL randomSel = funcionsArray[randomIndex];
[self performSelector:randomSel];
```

Comment: you can't do this because `SEL` is not objc object. however you can have `SEL array[7]`

Comment: ...and you have to add int randomIndex = arc4random() % [functionsArray count];

Comment: @xlc, thanks for the correction. The random number was a triviality so I decided to exlude it from the sample code.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
NSUInteger N = whatever;
NSUInteger randomIndex = arc4random_uniform((u_int32_t)N);
```

to get your uniform random index.

Then use that to access an array of function pointers, or preferably just use the index to create the data itself, as @nhahtdh suggested in the comments (that sounds way easier).